# Is there a way to compare 2 Strings without it being case-sensitive?

Tags: java, comparator

I've just spent almost hour debugging a `List<String>` in my code which was being sorted wrong by my `Comparator`.

Turns out that `string.compareTo(string2)` is case-sensitive. Meaning that all Capital letters come before the lowercase letters. e.g. "Z" comes before "d".

Is there any better way of comparing 2 `Strings` inside a `Comparator`and sorting them alphabetically ascending without them being case sensitive other then `string.toLowerCase().compareTo(string2.toLowerCase());` ?

Edit: There's a possibility of any accented letter appearing in my `String` like for example: ä, ö, ü, é, è, etc.

Comment: use `.equalsIgnoreCase()`

Comment: @SofoGial That checks equality only, not which is bigger or smaller which `copareTo` does and which is required to establish sorting order.

Comment: Do you use accented letters (or umlauts etc)?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException yes I do, sry for forgetting to Mention that. There's the possibility of accented letters existing like for example: ä, ö, ü, è, é, etc...

Comment: @D.Mendes While accented characters are handled by ignoring the case, it will assume a != ä but ä == Ä

Comment: Related (perhaps even duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220400/how-do-i-make-my-string-comparison-case-insensitive and for further information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885885/difference-between-collator-locale-sensitive-and-compareto-lexicographically

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two options provided in String itself:

- [`String.compareToIgnoreCase(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-): case insensitive variant of `compareTo`)
- [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER): `Comparator` that has the same ordering as `compareToIgnoreCase`
- or, for more advanced options like locale-specific rules, [`java.text.Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) and [`java.text.RuleBasedCollator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html)

As a tip: your first stop should be the Javadoc, not post a question on Stack Overflow: the Javadoc is extensive and will usually provide a quick answer.

Comment: Or java.text.Collator.

Comment: Yes, what @DodgyCodeException said, in case locale dependant order is required.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Thanks, added a link to that one as well.

Answer (score 6):

Use `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare`

Comment: What about accented letters?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException what about them?

Comment: @luk2302 CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER doesn't take locales into account. So it might deem f to come before é. The OP didn't specify whether é might possibly be present but it's not up to us to assume it won't be.

Answer (score 1):

use compareToIgnoreCase() method

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0):

## compareToIgnoreCase

The String Api has a second compare to function that does a compare while ignoring case.

```
string1.compareToIgnoreCase(string2);
```